# Approximate integer factorization

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, prime-numbers, factorization

Suppose we would like to compute an approximate prime factorization of a large integer `x` in the sense that the difference between `x` and its approximation is minimized. A naive way to state the problem in Mathematica is as follows.

```
n = 50;
x = RandomInteger[10^100];
vars = Map[z[#] &, Range[n]];
f = Abs[Times@@Map[Prime[#]^z[#] &, Range[n]] - x];
cons = Map[# >= 0 &, vars];
NMinimize[{f, cons}, vars \[Element] Integers]
```

The result is not very convincing and simply increasing `n` does not help. Do you have a better way to solve the problem?

**Update**: To account for the criticism presented by @yarchik, let me define the problem more precisely by demanding that the largest prime $p$ usable in the factorization must satisfy $10^p \leq x$. The naive Mathematica formulation above can be adapted as follows (being still naive but more precise).

```
x = RandomInteger[10^100];
p = {2};
While[NextPrime@Last@p <= Floor@Log[10, x], AppendTo[p, NextPrime@Last@p]];
n = Length[p];
vars = Map[z[#] &, Range[n]];
f = Abs[Times@@Map[#[[1]]^#[[2]] &, Thread[{p, vars}]] - x];
cons = Map[# >= 0 &, vars];
NMinimize[{f, cons}, vars \[Element] Integers]
```

Besides a better method to address this problem, I am also interested in lower and upper bounds of the solution for a given `x`.

**Update 2**: @DanielLichtblau suggested an encoding as knapsack problem which indeed improves the result obtained by `NMinimize`. One way to compute the resulting `vars` rules is as follows.

```
Thread[vars -> KnapsackSolve[Thread[{Log[p], Log[p]}], Log[x]]]
```

Comment: Not directly connected to you question, using indexed variables such as `z[1], z[2]` would enhanced the readability of your code. Another point is that there is an obvious limit to your function `f` that you try to minimize. Take the factors to be 2 and `[x/2]`. The error is at most 1. In other words, you need a better target function.

Comment: @yarchik: Thanks, I updated the formulation to increase readability. I would like the factors to be small compared to `x`. Are you aware of an upper/lower bound to the optimization problem given `x` and `n` (or a list of factors alternatively)?

Comment: Maybe set it up as a knapsack problem, using nonnegative integer sums of logs of small primes to approximate the log of the target integer.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you, great suggestion that improves the result and is even optimal if KnapsackSolve is optimal. If you like to write an answer, I will accept it. In the meantime, I mention your solution in the question.

Comment: Good to see it works. I cannot write it up as a real answer because I am away from Mathematica for another week. Since you worked out the details, it would be fine for you to write as a response. Certainly I would not be offended.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you. I keep your solution in "Update 2" in my post then.